# How to handle a list of learning resources

Tags: discussion

In some of my answers on mathematics stackexchange, I use generating functions.  I often feel this is a bit awkward because many of the readers, often including the original poster, are not familiar with these objects.  So in one of my recent answers, prompted by a comment by another user, I added a short list of resources for learning about GFs, as well as some information about common prerequisites and some out-and-out propaganda about why GFs are worthy of study.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140034/probability-of-matching-5-cards-from-a-deck-of-40).

So I was thinking that in future answers where I use GFs I may add a link to the previous answer, so that readers unfamiliar with GFs will have somewhere to get started.  But then I began to wonder if this is the best way.

Is there a better place to park such information so it can be easily referred to in future answers and won't get lost?

Comment: As I wrote in a comment to quid's answer, I believe it'll be better, if you wish to take the time & effort, to create your own self-answered question. Otherwise, even linking to your question will help to raise the profile, and in many cases the knowledge, about GFs.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Done.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142386/how-can-i-learn-about-generating-functions/3142387#3142387

Comment: I'm glad you did this, plus I hope the page will be grow & be maintained well over time. One small suggestion I have is that you link to the entire page, instead of just your answer, by removing the "#3142387" part at the end of the URL.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you for pointing that out. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142386/how-can-i-learn-about-generating-functions/3142387

Comment: I endorse generating function propaganda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I think it's fine to link to an answer. Some users do this frequently and over time have built up a nice collection of frequently useful posts.

That said, the system supports self-answered questions. Thus, rather than to have it in some answer. You could create a dedicate Q&A where you create both the question and the answer. Some users don't like this too much, but I think in some cases it can be useful and yours could be such a case.

Comment: When I read the question, my first thought was it would be better to instead create a dedicated question. I'm glad you suggested it as well. This way, the OP can also expand on what was written in the linked answer in the question text and their own answer. In addition, it would be easier & more reasonable for other people to include their own comments, links to other resources, and even additional answers. For a fairly topic like GFs, I believe this would be a better choice for the community, if the OP chooses to put the time & effort into doing this.